# Detecting different jailbreaks

Tags: mobile

I am using an application that shuts down and quits when it detects a jailbroken phone.

Is it possible that this application only detects some kinds of jailbreaks and not others? Or do applications generally detect jailbreaks by the result rather than the process?

Comment: You will have to talk to the developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say in your specific situation. What I can say is that there's basically an [arms race](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Bypassing_Jailbreak_Detection) between the author of jailbreak detection libraries and people creating apps to hide jailbreaks. Apps like [xCon](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/XCon) attempt to beat the detection libraries. Google "hiding jailbreak iOS 8" (or appropriate version).

Answer (score 2):

If you read [IOS Application Security Part 24 – Jailbreak Detection and Evasion](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-23-jailbreak-detection-evasion/) which is the first hit I get when googling for [detect jailbreak ios](https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+jailbreak+ios) then you will see that the common way is to look at the existence of software commonly installed after the jailbreak. What the code you have does exactly is not known but chances are high that it works in a similar way. This would also mean that it will only detect the jailbreaks which have the expected software installed, i.e. probably most but not all.

Generally there is no foolproof way to detect a jailbreak  because a jailbreaked system can simply lie to any applications asking for information about the system. This is similar to a rootkit inside a PC. And, if restrictions get added to some important software when it runs on a jailbroken device chances are high that somebody will find a way around it, either by hiding the jailbreak or simply by patching the application itself so that it can no longer detect the jailbreak.